# Trying to install Tizen Studio for the purpose of designing a smart watch face. Encountering an error when installing Tizen Studio

Tags: java, tizen

I bought a Samsung Gear S3 Frontier smart watch and would like to design a custom watch face. I have downloaded and installed the required Java SE Development Kit 9 from Oracle. When attempting to install Tizen Studio, I encounter the following error:

```
Cannot find the 64-Bit Java Development Kit (JDK). Check if the installed 64-Bit JDK version is 8 and over, or the JAVA_HOME environment variable is configured correctly.
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnn3D.png)

I found a helpful post regarding environment variables, but I still encounter the same error when trying to install Tizen Studio.

[Edit environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFU2.png)

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall new version of Java (9) and install Java 8 (JRE 1.8) from oracle. Set the path or environment variable. 
Install Tizen Studio again. Hopefully it will work. so far Tizen studio installer can't recognize new version of Java.

For Watch face design you can also try Gear Watch Designer (GWD) from Samsung Developer site. It is more easier tool for watch face design. http://developer.samsung.com/gear/design/watch-designer